# How to get WebStart to work with Netbeans 7.3.1 generated jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, java-web-start

I've use an earlier versions of Netbeans (6.9 ?) to get WebStart to run a Jar file, but later versions of Netbeans sometimes work, sometimes don't, now I'm using NB7.3.1, but the Jar file it generates can't run in WebStart mode, I've turned on the "Properties -> Run -> Run With WebStart", it generates a Jar file, when I double click on the jar file, the program runs, but when I opened the "preview-application.html" it generated, and hit Launch, it said : "Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Test_Tool/${JNLP.FILE}."

Some earlier versions can automatically replace the ${JNLP.FILE} with my file name, but later version don't do that. How to set it so it will automatically replace it like the earlier version that worked ?

Also this version can't seem to remember my setting, I opened the property panel and clicked "Run With WebStart", but next time I open the property panel, it's unchecked again. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, need to run dist/launch.html to get it started from local drive.

And need to adjust this line :

```
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost:8084/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
```

in the dist/launch.jnlp file, and copy : [ launch.jnlp , launch.html , *.jar ] to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\webapps\ROOT

Then start Tomcat, and load : `http://localhost:8084/launch.html`